# проблема с возвращаемым значением

Tags: python

Функция возвращает None вместо значения.

```
p1 = [['name','XXX xxx'],['w',22112]]
p2 = [['name','VVV vvv'],['w',11121]]
p3 = [['name','FFF fff'],['w',33322]]
p4 = [['name','AAA aaa'],['w',22134]]

people = [p1,p2,p3,p4]


def fun(mass,lable):
    for(fname,fvalue) in mass:
        if fname == lable:
            return fvalue

val = fun(people,'name')
print(val)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что `fname` у Вас это массив `['name','XXX xxx']` если нужно сравнить 'name' то можно так:

```
def fun(mass,lable):
    for(fname,fvalue) in mass:
        if fname[0] == lable:
            return fvalue
```